# ReactJs Product Details Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have an **API** with a working **Bearer** token.

I am listing all three products from the **API** on a product page. I would like to be able to click any of the items and display the information, on a product item detail page I created.

I have successfully created my routes and I am able to click around and open the relevant pages. The issue now is pulling details of an individual item on a item detail page using `params`, `props`, and `match` in ReactJS.

This is **App.js** file

```
import "./index.scss";
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Discover from "./pages/discover";
import ItemDetail from "./pages/itemDetail";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="discover" exact element={<Discover />} />
        <Route path="/itemDetail/:productCode" exact element={<ItemDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the products page, I have named it **discover** I am rendering all the products from the API on custom card components.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import StyledCard from "../components/Card";

const Discover = (props) => {
  const token = "3f224802-426e-3597-a2eb-7d35e6bff31d";
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setResult(json));
  }, []);

  const cardStyle = {
    listStyle: "none",
    margin: 5,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    minWidth: 240,
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="latestdeals container my-5">
        <h1>All Products</h1>
        <Row className="hotcards">
          <Col className="colcard">
            {(result?.result || []).map((item) => (
              <div key={item.productCode} style={cardStyle}>
                <a href={`/itemDetail/${item.productCode}`}>
                  {" "}
                  <StyledCard
                    key={item.productCode}
                    name={item.vendor}
                    title={item.description}
                    price={item.value}
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Discover;
```

Below is the item details page where I would like to display all the data inside that 1 specific item. I would also like to add the item to the **cart** (cart page) in the future.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function ItemDetail({ match }) {

    const [item, setItem] = useState({});
    const token = "3f224802-426e-3597-a2eb-7d35e6bff31d";

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(
        "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => setItem(json));
    }, []);

    console.log(item);

  return (
    <div>Item Detail</div>
  )
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

Now finally below is the results I get from the API

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "description": "PlayStation Store R50 Voucher ",
            "productCode": "317",
            "value": 50,
            "vendor": "Sony PlayStation"
        },
        {
            "description": "R1 - R2500 1Voucher Token",
            "productCode": "311",
            "value": 0,
            "vendor": "1Voucher"
        },
        {
            "description": "Refund 1Voucher Token",
            "productCode": "392",
            "value": 0,
            "vendor": "1Voucher"
        }
    ],
    "status": "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

- The `Discover` component is rendering a raw anchor (`<a />`) tag instead of the `Link` component provided from `react-router-dom`. This will reload the page when clicked, losing any saved React state.
- `ItemDetail` doesn't need to refetch the same data that `Discover` did. A simple solution could be to send the specific item in route state to the details page.

## Solution

Discover

Import the `Link` component and replace the anchor tag with it. Pass the current mapped item in route state. Remember to save the response `result` property into state instead of the entire result object.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Discover = (props) => {
  const token = "XXXXX";
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setResult(data.result)); // <-- save data.result
  }, []);

  ...

  return (
    <div className="latestdeals container my-5">
      <h1>All Products</h1>
      <Row className="hotcards">
        <Col className="colcard">
          {result.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.productCode} style={cardStyle}>
              <Link // <-- use Link component
                to={`/itemDetail/${item.productCode}`}
                state={{ item }} // <-- pass item object in state
              >
                <StyledCard
                  key={item.productCode}
                  name={item.vendor}
                  title={item.description}
                  price={item.value}
                />
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};
```

ItemDetail

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component API changed a bit from v5, there are no longer any [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), i.e. no `history`, `location`, and `match` props.

`ItemDetail` is a function component so it can use the React hooks, specifically the `useLocation` hook to access the passed route state. Since the data is passed in route state there's no need for the additional GET request.

Example:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function ItemDetail() {
  const { state } = useLocation(); // <-- access route state

  const { item } = state || {}; // <-- unpack the item from state
    
  console.log(item);

  

  return item ? (
    <div>
      <p>{item.description]</p>
      <p>{item.productCode]</p>
      <p>{item.value]</p>
      <p>{item.vendor]</p>
    </div>
  ) : "No item matched/found.";
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

Comment: now when I try to show the infomation, or console log the data. there is nothing

Comment: @ManassehZiki Was it displaying/logging previously? Are you referring to the `item` state that is updated with the GET response?

Comment: No Drew, it was not.

Comment: @ManassehZiki I see you've asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855000/how-can-i-display-a-single-product-from-this-api) regarding the rendering of details, which seems is a duplicate of your question here. Sorry, I must've been out of it last night because after taking another look over your code I've found other issues, including what you were really asking about, i.e. the rendering of the specific item details. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import Header from "../../components/Header"
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import "./Detail.scss"
const Detail = () => {
  const {id}= useParams()
  const [data,setData]=useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/robots/${id}`).then((res)=>{
      setData(res.data)
    })
  })
  return (
    <>
        <Header/>
    <div className="detail">
        <Helmet>
            <title>Detail Pages</title>
        </Helmet>


        <img src={data.image} alt="" />
        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
        <p>{data.desc}</p>
        <p>${data.price}</p>
        <Link to="/"> <button>Back to Home</button></Link>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Detail
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.